# Hi, when a user updates something from a user level I need history of updates I used a while loop to loop through

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';  

if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){

 $sqlQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE `table1` SET   `ATR`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ATR'])."' ");
$result = "SELECT  * FROM position";
$finalResult = mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error());

}
?>

<h2><font color="blue">Table that shows edit history:</h2>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0" width="60%">
     <tr>
     <th><strong>row1</strong></th>
     <th><strong>row2</strong></th>
     <th><strong>row3</strong></th>
     <th><strong>row4</strong></th>
     <th><strong>row5</strong></th>
     </tr>

     <?php 

   while($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($finalResult)) { 
         echo "<td>".$row5['row1']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row5['row2']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row5['row3']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row5['row4']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row5['row5']."</td>";
         continue;

     ?>



<?php


    mysql_close();


    }

    mysql_free_result($sqlQuery);





?>
```

Hi what I am trying to do is users being able to update and then it selects all their updates and loops through and displays all their updates. However, it only displays one update in the table I need all the rows and it dissapears after.

Comment: mysql_close should be out side of while loop

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated try to use mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: u have to use mysqli_* dont use mysql_

Comment: when I use mysqli it goes blank the screen